# I keep getting Compile Errors on the Exceptions Handling Java code I am writing for class, can someone see what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, exception

I had an assignment for class last week and I still am trying to figure out why my code wont compile without errors. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. (Very new to programing here)

The question for the week was this:

First, create three exception classes named NumberHighException, NumberLowException, and NumberNegativeException. Both NumberHighException and NumberLowException should be directly subclassed from the Exception class, but NumberNegativeException should be subclassed from NumberLowException. You can use the BadDataException class that was defined in this module as the model for your exception classes.

Next create a class called Verify that will be used to validate that a number is within a specified range. It should have one constructor that has two int parameters. The first parameter is the minimum number in the range, and the second parameter is the maximum number in the range.

In addition to the constructor, the Verify class should have one method that is named validate. The validate method should have a single parameter of data type int. The parameter contains the number that is being validated. If the value of the parameter is less than zero, the method should throw a NumberNegativeException. If the value is less than the minimum value of the range, it should throw a NumberLowException. If the value is greater than the maximum value of the range, it should throw a NumberHighException. If the value is within the specified range, no exception should be thrown.

Once all of these classes are created, create the driver class called Program5. The driver class should instantiate a Verify object with a range of 10 to 100. It should then do the following:

Prompt the user to input a number within the specified range.
Use a Scanner to read the user input as an int. You can ensure that an int was entered because the nextInt method throws an InputMismatchException if any non-digits are entered.
Call the validate method to validate that the number is within the range.
Print an appropriate error message if the value is not within the range, or print the value if it is within the range.

My code that I was able to create looked like this:

```
class NumberHighException extends Exception {
    public NumberHighException() {
    }

    public NumberHighException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "NumberHighException";
    }
}

class NumberLowException extends Exception {
    public NumberLowException() {
    }

    public NumberLowException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "NumberLowException";
    }
}

// negative number is a type of low number
class NumberNegativeException extends NumberLowException {

    public NumberNegativeException() {
    }

    public NumberNegativeException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "NumberNegativeException";
    }
}

class Verify {
    // lowest number in range
    private int minimum;
    // highest number in range
    private int maximum;

    // constructor sets minimum and maximum values in range
    public Verify(int minimum, int maximum) {
        this.minimum = minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

    // validate that number is within range
    public void validate(int number) throws NumberNegativeException, NumberLowException, NumberHighException

    {
        if (number < 0)
            throw new NumberNegativeException("number < 0");
        else if (number < minimum)
            throw new NumberLowException("number < 10");
        else if (number > maximum)
            throw new NumberHighException("number > 100");
    }
}

class Program5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0;
        int returnCode = 0;
        int minimum = 10;
        int maximum = 100;

        // create object to verify number is within range 10 to 100
        Verify ok = new Verify(minimum, maximum);

        // create Scanner object to read keyboard
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // prompt for input
        System.out.print("Enter number between " + minimum + " and " + maximum + ": ");

        try {
            // read int from keyboard
            // throws exception if non digits are entered
            number = input.nextInt();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("You entered a non digit");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // validate that entered number is within specified range
        try {
            ok.validate(number);
        } catch (NumberHighException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberHighException: " + e.getMessage());
            returnCode = 2;
        }

        // because NumberNegativeException is subclass of NumberLowException
        // it must be caught before NumberLowException or compile error results
        catch (NumberNegativeException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberNegativeException: " + e.getMessage());
            returnCode = 3;
        }

        catch (NumberLowException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberLowException: " + e.getMessage());
            returnCode = 4;
        }

        finally {
            // true is number entered was within range
            if (returnCode == 0)
                System.out.println(number + " is valid number");
        }
        System.exit(returnCode);
    }
}
```

I checked each section step by step and it didn't start having errors till the last part when I added the Program5 to the code. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: At-least tell us what is the error you are getting instead of just "I am getting error".

Comment: Learn to delete bad posts. When every body downvotes you there are some reason for this. You are not even having enough repo to lose.

Comment: Please tell the error that you are getting

Comment: The errors are: Program6.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);            
^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Program5
Program6.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);            
                    ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class Program5
Program6.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
catch(InputMismatchException e)       
      ^
  symbol:   class InputMismatchException
  location: class Program5
3 errors

Comment: I compiled your program your program it ran fine i just added imports and public keyword in front of the class program5 and it ran exacly fine

Comment: This is a _lot_ of text for a compilation error. Please try to find the shortest piece of code that reproduces the error, and post just that. We also don't need to know everything (or likely anything!) about the assignment, since the assignment doesn't affect the compiler. Please also include the text of the error, and note which line it's on. In short: please make this question easier to read and answer. The "dump it all and let someone else do the work" approach is probably the source of your downvotes here.

Comment: Why would I delete a post when I still want to know the answer afzalex? Im sorry if my question isn't up to your standard but I am just trying to learn here.

Comment: I'm using jGRASP to compile my code, would that make a difference?

Comment: @BeachLover8 Your Java knowledge, your programming skills, and your learning state are completely irrelevant when it comes to the topic: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) In short: Reduce the text drastically. Indent your code properly. Tell the exact error and the line where it occurs. Try to minimize your code to a reproducable example.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I have ever used this site to ask a question. I just thought I was giving a short description of my problem. Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code... May be it can help you...

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException; //added the import
import java.util.Scanner; // added the import

class NumberHighException extends Exception {
    public NumberHighException() {}
    public NumberHighException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "NumberHighException";
    }
}

class NumberLowException extends Exception {
    public NumberLowException() {}
    public NumberLowException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "NumberLowException";
    }
}

// negative number is a type of low number 
class NumberNegativeException extends NumberLowException {

    public NumberNegativeException() {}
    public NumberNegativeException(String str) {
        super(str);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "NumberNegativeException";
    }
}

class Verify {
    // lowest number in range    
    private int minimum;
    // highest number in range    
    private int maximum;
    // constructor sets minimum and maximum values in range    
    public Verify(int minimum, int maximum) {
        this.minimum = minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }
    // validate that number is within range    
    public void validate(int number)
    throws NumberNegativeException, NumberLowException, NumberHighException

    {
        if (number < 0) throw new NumberNegativeException("number < 0");
        else if (number < minimum) throw new NumberLowException("number < 10");
        else if (number > maximum) throw new NumberHighException("number > 100");
    }
}

public class Program5 // added the public keyword
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0;
        int returnCode = 0;
        int minimum = 10;
        int maximum = 100;

        // create object to verify number is within range 10 to 100       
        Verify ok = new Verify(minimum, maximum);

        // create Scanner object to read keyboard       
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        // prompt for input       
        System.out.print("Enter number between " + minimum +
            " and " + maximum + ": ");

        try {
            // read int from keyboard          
            // throws exception if non digits are entered          
            number = input.nextInt();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("You entered a non digit");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // validate that entered number is within specified range              
        try {
            ok.validate(number);
        } catch (NumberHighException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberHighException: " + e.getMessage());
            returnCode = 2;
        }

        // because NumberNegativeException is subclass of NumberLowException       
        // it must be caught before NumberLowException or compile error results       
        catch (NumberNegativeException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberNegativeException: " + e.getMessage());
            returnCode = 3;
        } catch (NumberLowException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberLowException: " + e.getMessage());
            returnCode = 4;
        } finally {
            // true is number entered was within range          
            if (returnCode == 0) System.out.println(number + " is valid number");
        }
        System.exit(returnCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That does work. Now I just need to really take some time and look it over to see what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `Scanner` class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Program5  
{    
public static void main(String [] args)
```